# How do I automate the opening, saving, and closing of an Excel file on Windows?

Tags: windows, automation

I have a client who automatically receives reports in Excel format. The files have a `.xlsx` extension. They use FileMaker to manipulate the data into a format they prefer.

FileMaker supports the importing of `.xlsx` files, but chokes on these files unless they're opened, saved and closed in Excel. All that needs to be done is to open the file, save it, and close it. No changes are made to the contents. This works when they do it on Windows or I do it on macOS.

If they were using macOS, I'd use AppleScript to automate this process. Is there a native Windows method for doing this?

Comment: You should be able to use "Excel.Application" to automate Excel via COM, this can be used via PowerShell for example.  Google "Excel.Application" and COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HelpingHand pointed me in the right direction. I ended up learning enough VB Script and wrote a small double-clickable script that converts files at a specific path from Excel to CSV.

```vb
set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xls.DisplayAlerts = False

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set w_shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

desktop = w_shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
folder_path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(desktop) & "\Payroll\"

set folder = fso.GetFolder(folder_path)
set files = folder.Files

for each file in files
    path = folder_path & file.Name
    set workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(path)
    path = Replace(path, "xlsx", "csv")
    workbook.SaveAs path, 6
    workbook.Close False
next

xls.Quit
```